# show that if $x \in \ell_2 (\mathbb{N})$ then the serie $\sum_{j \geq 1 } \frac{x_j}{j}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis

If $\ell_2(\mathbb{N)}=\{x: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C} :\sum_{j \geq1 } |x_j|^2  < \infty \}$

show that if $x \in \ell_2 (\mathbb{N})$ then the serie $\sum_{j \geq 1 } \frac{x_j}{j}$ converges.

my try how $x\in\ell_2(\mathbb{N})$ , we have that

$\sum \frac{x_j}{j} \leq (\sum |x_j|^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} (\sum |\frac{1}{j^2}|)^\frac{1}{2}$ but $\sum |x_j|^2$ is bounded and $\sum |\frac{1}{j^2}|$ is bounded too, so $\sum \frac{x_j}{j}$ is bounded so it converges

Comment: Yes. What’s the question?

Comment: @Eric if i was right hehe

Comment: Yes. Could use more detail (where did the inequality come from, what stops it from going to neg infinity, etc.) but basic idea is right.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down your argument. We should first recall (Bunyakovsky-)Cauchy-Schwarz: Suppose $u_n, v_n$ are square-summable sequences. Then

$$\left( \sum_n u_n v_n \right)^2 \leq \left( \sum_n u_n ^2 \right) \left( \sum_n v_n ^2 \right).$$

Now with $u_n = x_n$ and $v_n = \frac{1}{j}$ we get

$$\left( \sum_n \frac{x_n}{n} \right)^2 \leq \left( \sum_n x_n ^2 \right) \left( \sum_n \frac{1}{j^2} \right) \leq \frac{S \pi^2}{6}$$

where $S = \sum_{n} x_n .$ Thus $$\sum_n \frac{x_n}{n} < \infty$$ by comparison.

Your argument works!